# warning: ‘fp’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

Tags: c

I'm trying to open [this file](http://xato.net/files/10k%20most%20common.zip) in the function openFile and pass it to the function commonPasswd but I'm getting a warning when I try to compile.

```
warning: ‘fp’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     if ( openFile (fp) ) {
          ^
```

If I run it I get a Segmentation fault (core dumped). For checking you can do ./program 34JBXiZ7tYKF.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
static const char alphabet[] = "abc";
bool checkPass (const char* key, const char* hash, const char* salt)
{    
    if ( !strcmp (crypt (key, salt), hash) )
        return true;
    return false;
}
bool openFile (FILE* fp)
{
    if ( (fp = fopen ("./commonPasswd.txt", "r")) == NULL ) 
            return false;
    return true;
}
bool commonPasswd (const char* hash, const char* salt)
{
    char* buf = calloc (20, sizeof (char));
    FILE* fp;
    if ( openFile (fp) ) {
        while ( fgets (buf, 20, fp) != NULL ) {
            if ( checkPass (buf, hash, salt) )
                return true;
            free (buf);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
bool DES (char* argv[])
{
    char salt[2];
    strncpy(salt, argv[1], 2 * sizeof (char));
    if ( commonPasswd (argv[1], salt) )
        return true;
    return false;
}
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf ("Usage: ./crack passwd\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if ( DES (argv) )
        return 0;
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: Does the `crypt` function know that `salt` is exactly 2 chars long? Because `salt` doesn't necessarily contain the `\0` value, so if it is handled as a string inside `crypt`, this could lead to the seg fault.

Comment: yes, it knows that salt is 2 chars long or it can also accept an argument like '$1$anySizeSALT$' for md5 encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool commonPasswd (const char* hash, const char* salt)
{
    char* buf = calloc (20, sizeof (char));
    FILE* fp;
    printf ("Checking if the password is a common one\n");
    if ( openFile (&fp) ) {
        while ( fgets (buf, 20, fp) != NULL ) {
            if ( checkPass (buf, hash, salt) )
                return true;
            free (buf);
        }
    }
    printf ("The password isn't a common one\n");
    return false;
}
bool openFile (FILE** fp)
{
    if ( (*fp = fopen ("./commonPasswd.txt", "r")) == NULL ) {
        system ("wget -O commonPasswd.zip 'http://xato.net/files/10k%20most%20common.zip'");
        system ("unzip commonPasswd.zip");
        remove ("commonPasswd.zip");
        rename ("10k most common.txt", "commonPasswd.txt");
        if ( (*fp = fopen ("./commonPasswd.txt", "r")) == NULL ){
            printf ("The file couldn't be openend\n");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a pointer to the pointer if you want to modify the pointer object.

```
bool openFile (FILE **fp)
```

then also update the function call and the function body accordingly.

Comment: I'm getting a lot of errors when I update the function call and the function body. What can I see to understand this?

Comment: @Arturo edit your question and add an addendum with the new program at the end of the question

Comment: @Arturo I said to *add an addendum with the new program at the end of the question* not to modify your existing question otherwise all the answers will no longer make sense.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't write more code. The web complained.

Comment: @Arturo in that case revert your changes and open a new question, you should never modify your question example if there  are already answers.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are passed by value. When the assignment `fp = fopen(...)` is done inside `openFile`, this does not change the value of `fp` in `commonPasswd`.

You need to pass either a pointer-to-pointer to `openFile`, change `openFile` to return the `FILE*`, or just drop that function and call `open` directly.